# Logic error; File not opening when called from dir

Tags: python, function, input, directory

Below is a function that is supposed to allow a user to see a list of files from a directory and type in one to open. Everything seems to work smoothly and I get no syntax error, though when I type in the name of the file I want to open it does nothing. Any solutions?

```
def openFile(dirName):
        """Allows user to view list of files in directory and view them."""
        lyst = os.listdir(dirName)
        for element in lyst: print(element)
        userinput = input('Enter file name: ')
        if userinput in lyst:
            open(userinput)
        else:
            print('\nFile not in directory\n')
        return (userinput, 'r')
```

Comment: (1) `open` returns a file object. To make anything happen, you must do something with it. (2) If `dirname` isn't the current working directory, the file can't be found. You must `os.path.join` directory and file name.

Comment: There is no problem with the current directory showing up but when I type in the file to open, it does not open.

Comment: Or do you mean to start the application associated with the file? If so, on Windows there is `os.startfile` for this.

Comment: No I just mean open the file, when I type in the filename the file does not open. Is it something to do with my return statetement?

Comment: The return statement doesn't return the file object.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the file is opening?

Comment: I'm expecting it to open the python file that is being called.

Comment: Do you mean to `import` a Python module? Or execute a Python script in a new process?

Comment: Bascically what this is supposed to do is list all my python files and when I type one into the input it should open the file that is being called, but it doesnt. I dont get any syntax errors but the fire doe not open

Comment: There are the simple `os.system` or `subprocess.call` to execute programs like the Python interpreter similar to the way it is done on commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Originally you had:

```
if userinput in lyst:
    file = open(userinput)
[...]
return (userinput, 'r')
```

`userinput` is a string, not a file. For example, `userinput` might be "`myfile.txt`".

So, you are returning a tuple `("myfile.txt", 'r')`. The letter 'r' is not opening a file in read-only mode, it's just the letter '`r`'. You returned a pair of short strings, one of which is always the letter '`r`'

---

Perhaps you want the following?

```
if userinput in lyst:
    file = open(userinput, mode='r')
[...]
return file
```

That's kind of dangerous, because you'll have to remember to close the file later.

---

Another problem is that you need to go inside of the folder which the user specifies before you can open the file that is inside of that folder.

---

One of the following two pieces of code should work for you:

```
import pathlib as pl
import os
def openFile(dirName):
    """Allows user to view list of files in directory and view them."""
    lyst = os.listdir(dirName)
    for element in lyst:
        print(element)
    filename = input('Enter file name: ')
    if filename in lyst:
        os.startfile(pl.Path(dirName) / filename)
    else:
        print('\nFile not in directory\n')
    return
```

or

```
import pathlib as pl
import os
def openFile(dirName):
    """Allows user to view list of files in directory and view them."""
    lyst = os.listdir(dirName)
    for element in lyst:
        print(element)
    filename = input('Enter file name: ')
    if filename in lyst:
        file = open(pl.Path(dirName) / filename, mode="r")
    else:
        print('\nFile not in directory\n')
    return file # dangerous! don't forget to call file.close()!
```